# ¿Como detectar Sub Procesos en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola me gustaría saber como se detecta un hilo, Proceso o Sub Proceso dentro de una aplicación.
Me gustaría realizar una estructura para enviar una alerta cuándo el usuario necesite cerra la aplicación
pero al mismo tiempo esta realizando acciones con ella.

Ejemplo

```
   if(AlgunProcesoDetectado == true){
        //Envia una alerta para que no cierra la aplicación
   }else{
       //Cierra la aplicación 
       Application.Exit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede esto ya fue respondido en el foro en inglés, debes adaptarlo a tu necesidad: [Documentación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189381/4717133)

> **[Traduccion]** Da la casualidad de que tengo un poco de código C # / WMI por ahí que mata todos los procesos generados por una identificación de proceso específica, de forma recursiva. obviamente, el asesinato no es lo que desea, pero el hallazgo de procesos secundarios parece ser lo que le interesa. Espero que esto sea útil:

### Script

```
    private static void KillAllProcessesSpawnedBy(UInt32 parentProcessId)
    {
        logger.Debug("Finding processes spawned by process with Id [" + parentProcessId + "]");

        // NOTE: Process Ids are reused!
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM Win32_Process " +
            "WHERE ParentProcessId=" + parentProcessId);
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            logger.Debug("Killing [" + collection.Count + "] processes spawned by process with Id [" + parentProcessId + "]");
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                UInt32 childProcessId = (UInt32)item["ProcessId"];
                if ((int)childProcessId != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
                {
                    KillAllProcessesSpawnedBy(childProcessId);

                    Process childProcess = Process.GetProcessById((int)childProcessId);
                    logger.Debug("Killing child process [" + childProcess.ProcessName + "] with Id [" + childProcessId + "]");
                    childProcess.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```